# Remove Item Without Mutating State in Redux

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, immutable.js

The first thing I tried was this:

```
const initialState = {
  items: {},
  showCart: false,
  showCheckout: false,
  userID: null
};

export default function reducer(state=Immutable.fromJS(initialState), action) {
  case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART':
    return state.deleteIn(['items', String(action.id)]);
}
```

When console logging the deleteIn above, it does actually remove the item from the Map correctly. However, the app doesn't re-render again, because I assume I'm mutating the state(?). (mapStateToProps gets called, but no new state).

So next I tried this:

```
case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART':
  const removed = state.deleteIn(['items', String(action.id)]);
  const removeItemState = {
    ...state,
    items: { removed } 
  }
  return state.mergeDeep(removeItemState);
```

But I'm just adding the deleted item to the items again, creating a duplication.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting more code (such as my reducers setup) *may*  have helped more, but here's what was going on:

First, this code was the right way to remove the item from the state.

```
return state.deleteIn(['items', String(action.id)]);
```

However, because I was using the `immutable` library and not `redux-immutable` for my combineReducers, my state was not properly being handled. This was allowing me to do things like `state.cart.items` (in mapStateToProps) where really I should've been using `state.getIn(['cart', 'items'])`.

Changing that magically made the delete work.

Thanks to @jslatts in the Reactiflux Immutable Slack channel for help with figuring this out!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the item after you've [deeply cloned](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html#correct-approach-copying-all-levels-of-nested-data) the state?

```
case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART':
    const removeItemState = {
        ...state
        items: {
            ...state.items
        }
    };

    delete removeItemState.items[String(action.id)];

    return removeItemState;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about reduce?

```
case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART':
  return {
    ...state,
    items: Object.keys(state.items).reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (curr !== action.id) acc[curr] = state.items[curr];
      return acc;
    }, {})
  };
```